# How to get last modifying user information using google drive API?

Tags: c#, google-drive-api

In `Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File` class it just provides name of the last modifying user. How to obtain full info of the user (like email, user id etc.)?

```
var service = new DriveService(auth);
Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File file = service.Files.Get("fileid").Fetch();
file.LastModifyingUserName;// = "User Name" //How to get email id of this user?
```

In an organization there can be more than one person with the same first and last name. It is user id which differentiates. So I need email ID.

```
E.g Allan Donald => allan1@corp.com
    Allan Donald => allan2@corp.com
```

This is very much possible.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/drive/credentials

Comment: https://developers.google.com/drive/examples/dotnet for c sharp

Comment: I think you din't get the problem correctly. I have edited my post for better clarity.

Comment: `LastModifyingUserName` contains that information

Comment: LastModifyingUserName contains just the name and not the email id or user id. But I need user id or email id of the Last Modifying User.

Comment: It's impossible to retrieve user emails with the current permissions model and API features we have. We're working on to improve it though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out how to do it in the Java API. It's far from elegant, but it works.

```
File file; // start with your file
User user = file.getLastModifyingUser();
Permission permission = service.permissions().get(file.getId(), user.getPermissionId()).execute();
String email = permission.getEmailAddress();
```

You can also use the RevisionList interface to get all the modifying users.

Comment: Yes. This method is not available in 3.5 version of SDK.