# Google Drive Android not returning latest version of the file

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

I'm using Drive Android API to sync a file between devices and to hold the latest version on Drive. Since some time ago it started behaving really strange.

To see that a file exists and get it's latest version, I do a Query search by that file name and sorting by modified date descending. It returns the correct datetime when the file was updated:

```
        final SortOrder sortOrder = new SortOrder.Builder()
                .addSortDescending(SortableField.MODIFIED_DATE)
                .build();
        final Query query = new Query.Builder()
                .addFilter(Filters.eq(SearchableField.TITLE, "fileName"))
                .addFilter(Filters.eq(SearchableField.TRASHED, false))
                .setSortOrder(sortOrder)
                .build();
        Drive.DriveApi.query(apiClient, query)
                .setResultCallback(lastModifiedCallback);
```

But when I query the file contents, it returns some older version of it. I couldn't understand what causes it.

I read the file as follows:

```
                driveId.asDriveFile()
                .open(apiClient, DriveFile.MODE_READ_ONLY, null)
                .setResultCallback(fileContentsCallback);
```

The drive contents I read as follows:

```
            final DriveContents driveContents = result.getDriveContents();
            final InputStream inputStream = driveContents.getInputStream();
            final File newFile = new File("fileName");
            final FileOutputStream dest = new FileOutputStream(newFile);
            ByteStreams.copy(inputStream, dest);
            driveContents.commit(apiClient, null);
```

Any ideas why it's happening and how to fix it?

I know that the version returned is old, because if I use the Drive application on my device, it returns the correct, latest version of the same file.

Comment: Is your query returning a list of revisions? That will certainly include the older versions. Did you try fetching the one found in the first index of the response? Try this [SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16609823/how-to-get-last-modified-user-information-using-google-drive-api) also, it might help.

Comment: @noogui metadataBuffer.getCount() returns 1 and I get the first one.

Comment: also, I should add to make it clear - the query for the last modified works ok, returns the latest. The issue is then with getting the real contents of the file using not query, but 'open' method.

Comment: It is a known bug in the Google drive, https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4727. It is expected to be fixed in November, 2016.

Comment: @h22 Yes, thank you, I'm watching that bug since I posted the question.

Comment: Seeing same thing now, over 2 years later, with play-services-drive:16.0.0