# How to get last modifying user email address from Google Drive Ruby API

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm new to the Google Drive API and I'm having a hard time finding my answer in the documentation and other posts.  I'm writing a Ruby script to move files to/from a Google Team Drive and would like to be able to see each of those files' last modifying user's email address.  I can run my query in the API Explorer and get the result I'm looking for, but when I run the same query from my script, I can only see the last modifying user's display name and a couple other data points, but no email address.  I'm using a service account I created to authenticate with the API and have given that service account Full access on the Team Drive and Domain-wide Delegation permissions.  Below is my code.  Can anyone offer any suggestions?

```
require 'google/apis/drive_v3'
require 'googleauth'

SCOPES = [
  Google::Apis::DriveV3::AUTH_DRIVE,
  Google::Apis::DriveV3::AUTH_DRIVE_APPDATA,
  Google::Apis::DriveV3::AUTH_DRIVE_FILE,
  Google::Apis::DriveV3::AUTH_DRIVE_METADATA,
  Google::Apis::DriveV3::AUTH_DRIVE_METADATA_READONLY,
  Google::Apis::DriveV3::AUTH_DRIVE_PHOTOS_READONLY,
  Google::Apis::DriveV3::AUTH_DRIVE_READONLY
]

ENV['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = "/path/to/my/service/account/creds.json"

service = Google::Apis::DriveV3::DriveService.new
service.authorization = Google::Auth.get_application_default(SCOPES)

response = service.list_files(
  q: "'team drive id' in parents",
  include_team_drive_items: true,
  supports_team_drives: true
)
```

Edit:

The response object is as follows:

```
#<Google::Apis::DriveV3::FileList:<memory location> @files=[#<Google::Apis::DriveV3::File:<memory location> @capabilities=#<Google::Apis::DriveV3::File::Capabilities:<memory location> @can_add_children=false, @can_change_viewers_can_copy_content=true, @can_comment=true, @can_copy=true, @can_delete=true, @can_download=true, @can_edit=true, @can_list_children=false, @can_move_item_into_team_drive=true, @can_move_team_drive_item=true, @can_read_revisions=true, @can_read_team_drive=true, @can_remove_children=false, @can_rename=true, @can_share=true, @can_trash=true, @can_untrash=true>, @created_time=<created time>, @explicitly_trashed=false, @has_augmented_permissions=true, @has_thumbnail=true, @icon_link=<icon link>, @id=<id>, @is_app_authorized=false, @kind=\"drive#file\", @last_modifying_user=#<Google::Apis::DriveV3::User:<memory location> @display_name=<display name>, @kind=\"drive#user\", @me=false, @permission_id=<permission id>, @photo_link=<photo link>>, @mime_type=<mime type>, @modified_by_me=false, @modified_time=<modified time>, @name=<name>, @parents=[<parent id>], @quota_bytes_used=0, @spaces=[\"drive\"], @starred=false, @team_drive_id=<team drive id>, @thumbnail_link=<thumbnail link>, @thumbnail_version=<thumbnail version>, @trashed=false, @version=<version>, @viewed_by_me=false, @viewers_can_copy_content=true, @web_view_link=<web view link>], @incomplete_search=false, @kind=\"drive#fileList\">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll demo the concept in Javascript, you translate it to Ruby. Two ways you can do this.

**1. Using Files.list for all files**

Since I see you're using [Files.list](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/list) let's answer that first. You have to know the hierarchy of your JSON metadata which is found in [Files resource](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files#resource).

To access `lastModifyingUser` property use
`file.lastModifyingUser.emailAddress` where `file` is  `var file = response.result.files;` which contains an array list of your drive files.

**2. Using Revisions.get for a specific file**

To get `lastModifyingUser`, you can use [Revisions.get](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/revisions/get#try-it). When using this method you have to know the `revisionId` (it's a revision number you obtain using `revisions.list`). You can try using 1 as `revisionId` for testing purposes.

Here's my JS code:

```
 function revisionGet() {
        gapi.client.drive.revisions.get({
          'fileId': '123456789ABCDEFG',
          'revisionId': 1,
          'fields': '*'
        }).then(function(response) {
  
          var getResponse = response;
          console.log(getResponse.result);

          appendPre('displayName: ' + getResponse.result.lastModifyingUser.displayName );
          appendPre('email: ' + getResponse.result.lastModifyingUser.emailAddress );
        });
      }
```

The `wildcard *` being passed in 'fields' property just means, return all metadata. `appendPre` is just a custom function to display in HTML.
The important bit is to know how to access the `emailAddress` property using

```
response.result.lastModifyingUser.emailAddress
```

**My HTML output:**

```
displayName: noogui
email: mypersonalemail@gmail.com
```

To see the JSON hierarchy of revision metadata go to [revision file resource](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/revisions#resource).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however I already know the hierarchy of the JSON metadata.  The issue is that `file.last_modifying_user.email_address => nil`

Comment: can you print your "response" object?

Comment: I added the response to my post because it was too long for a comment.

Comment: I was able to get the email address using the method i found on this other post.  I just translated it into Ruby. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16609823/how-to-get-last-modified-user-information-using-google-drive-api)