# Does file.LastModifyingUser.EmailAddress return a value?

Tags: google-drive-api

Whenever I try to access a Drive file's LastModifyingUser from a C# app, the email address is always null. I can get the address when I use the same query in the API explorer so I'm wondering if there's an issue with the library or if I'm just missing something.

This sounds like the same issue as is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45947413/how-to-get-last-modifying-user-email-address-from-google-drive-ruby-api/) but the proposed workaround didn't work for me.

For reference here is my request code:

```
FilesResource.ListRequest recordFoldersRequest = service.Files.List();
recordFoldersRequest.Fields = "nextPageToken, files(*)";
recordFoldersRequest.SupportsTeamDrives = true;
recordFoldersRequest.IncludeTeamDriveItems = true;
recordFoldersRequest.Corpora = "teamDrive";

var result = recordFoldersRequest.Execute();
var files = result.Files;

if (files != null && files.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File file in files)
    {
        //file.LastModifyingUser.EmailAddress is always null here
    }
}
```

Comment: from https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/drive/v3/csharp/latest/classGoogle_1_1Apis_1_1Drive_1_1v3_1_1Data_1_1User.html#a5713db1041ed1d0d2f2e1ba8cfe22830, "The email address of the user. This may not be present in certain contexts if the user has not made their email address visible to the requester."

Comment: Thanks for that, any idea where that setting is located?

Comment: it's probably referring to whether or not the user granted profile permission to your app as part of the authorisation flow. If not, and if it's important, you need to add the appropriate openid scope.